# Rx fromPromise and retry

Tags: rxjs

Why do you have to **flatMap** the **fromPromise** to get the **retry** to work ?
*(The '/error' returns a status 500)*

```
var responseStream = Rx.Observable.just('/error').
        flatMap(requestUrl => {
            return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(_this.$http.get(requestUrl));
    });

    responseStream.
        retry(3).
        subscribe(
        function (x) {
            console.log('Next: ' + x);
        },
        function (err) {
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
        },
        function () {
            console.log('Completed');
        });
```

I would like to cut on the ceremonial and just have:

```
Rx.Observable.fromPromise(_this.$http.get('error')).
        retry(3).
        subscribe(
        function (x) {
            console.log('Next: ' + x);
        },
        function (err) {
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
        },
        function () {
            console.log('Completed');
        });
```

In that second case the xhr call is only executed once.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Because `Promises` don't have an API for retrying. [`fromPromise`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/perf/operators/frompromise.js) is just wrapping the `Promise` and making it emit through an Observable instead. When you call `_this.$http.get('error')` you have already created a `Promise` and it is already in flight, so there is no way to retry the promise without calling the method again.

The reason it works when wrapped with `flatMap` is because when you retry the `Observable` it is actually re-executing the method that generates the promise.

If verbosity is really hurting you, realize that many of the operators support `Promises` implicitly, without the need to call the `fromPromise` method.

So your example could be reduced down to

```
var responseStream = Rx.Observable.just('/error')
        .flatMap(requestUrl => _this.$http.get(requestUrl));

    responseStream
        .retry(3)
        .subscribe(
          (x) => console.log('Next: ' + x),
          (err) => console.log('Error: ' + err),
          () => console.log('Completed'));
```

Or even more simply using `defer`:

```
Observable.defer(() => _this.$http.get('/error'))
   .retry(3)
   .subscribe(
      (x) => console.log('Next: ' + x),
      (err) => console.log('Error: ' + err),
      () => console.log('Completed'));
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: @paulpdaniels can i simply wrap the promise into a plain function and then provide that to fromPromise like : Rx.Observable.fromPromise(getRequest).retry.... where getRequest is plain function which returns promise. that is: function getRequest() { return  _this.$http.get('/error')); }

Comment: @ShaileshVaishampayan depends on which version of RxJS you are using. RxJS 4 allows you to pass functions to `fromPromise` that are lazily evaluated at subscribe time, however, that is missing in RxJS 5. Either way, `defer` works in both cases

Comment: @paulpdaniels thanks. BTW looks like your book rxjs in action is not available in India .at least not on Amazon. Hope it's plan to publish it here as well. want to buy it asap :)

Comment: @ShaileshVaishampayan you should be able to get it directly through the Manning website :)